# alphavantage fx market data download through api using python is providing the wrong time interval

Tags: python, api, intervals, forex, alpha-vantage

I am downloading csv FX data from alphavantage.com using Python. I request a 60min interval but the returned data shows a timestamp of 1 minute per row.

```
fxurl="https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_INTRADAY&from_symbol=EUR&to_symbol=USD&interval=60min&apikey=XXX&datatype=csv"
s2=requests.get(fxurl).content
fxdf=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s2.decode('utf-8')))
print(fxdf)
```

The output generated is:

```
           timestamp    open    high     low   close
0   2020-06-05 22:28:00  1.1291  1.1291  1.1291  1.1291
1   2020-06-05 22:27:00  1.1291  1.1291  1.1291  1.1291
2   2020-06-05 22:26:00  1.1291  1.1291  1.1291  1.1291
3   2020-06-05 22:25:00  1.1291  1.1291  1.1291  1.1291
4   2020-06-05 22:24:00  1.1291  1.1291  1.1291  1.1291
..                  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
95  2020-06-05 20:53:00  1.1289  1.1289  1.1289  1.1289
96  2020-06-05 20:52:00  1.1289  1.1289  1.1289  1.1289
97  2020-06-05 20:51:00  1.1287  1.1287  1.1287  1.1287
98  2020-06-05 20:50:00  1.1291  1.1291  1.1291  1.1291
99  2020-06-05 20:49:00  1.1289  1.1289  1.1289  1.1289

[100 rows x 5 columns]
```

Could someone please help me understand why I am getting 1-minute timestamp intervals instead of 60 minute.

Thanks very much, Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

ts = TimeSeries (key='your api key', output_format = "pandas")

data_daily, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol='tsla', outputsize ='compact', interval='60min')

print (data_daily)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jakub, thanks for answering but it looks like you didn't read my question carefully enough.  I specified 60min and got 1min.  You seem to think I wanted 1 min.  Please take another look, thanks.

Comment: Heya sorry I misread everything. I edited the answer with the code that I just tried and it works. I am not sure on how to fix it the way you are doing it bc you are importing a csv. I am still new to python, but maybe you can do something with this pandas dataframe.